# Sort multidimensional and associative array by a deeply nested array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, database, sorting

I have a multidimensional array that I fetch from a database and it's structured like this:

```
array(SESSION
      array(items
            array(DatabaseID
                  (ItemName, ItemCategory, Children, 
                                                    array(Id1, Id2, Id3...)         
                                                       etc..))))
```

I am not sure that this is how you write it since I'm a beginner but I hope you get the struture. If I want to acess the ItemCategory of a certain item, I save the item's DatabaseID in $DatabaseID and write:

```
$_SESSION['items'][$DatabaseID]['ItemCategory'];
```

If I want an array with the items children's DatabaseID I write:

```
$_SESSION['items'][$DatabaseID]['Children'];
```

Now, I want to sort this array. I have looked around but I don't understand how to sort it after exactly what I want. I would like to sort the whole

```
$_SESSION['items']
```

according to the ItemName instead of the DatabaseID. Is this at all possible? I mean, the ItemName is stored for each DatabaseID...

I want to use this in order print all the Items sorted by their name instead of their DatabaseID.

### Edit

I have tried

```
array_multisort($_SESSION['items'], $_SESSION['items']['DatabaseID']['ItemName']);
```

but the problem is that

```
 $_SESSION['items']['DatabaseID']['ItemName']
```

is not an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: Unfortunally not... @Epodax

Comment: In the last two coding examples, you are purposely stating "DatabaseID", but when you actually try to access it in code you replace with the variable `$DatabaseID` right?

Answer (score 0):

An easier and faster solutiom is to use the SQL ORDER BY clause.

The syntax is:

`SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column1, column2, ... ASC|DESC;`

You should add this clause onto your existing SQL statement.